# Error from VideoCompress: Method: getFileThumbnail PlatformException(video_compress,

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting an exception thrown in getpreviewimage() and I am also getting  Null check operator used on a null value.

```
compressvideo() async{
    if (widget.imageSource == ImageSource.gallery){
      return widget.videofile;
    }
    else{
      final  compressvideo = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(
        widget.videopath,
        quality: VideoQuality.MediumQuality);
      return compressvideo?.file;
    }  
  }

  getpreviewimage()async{
    final previewimage = await VideoCompress.getFileThumbnail(widget.videopath);
    return previewimage;   
  }
  Future<String> uploadvideostorage(String id) async{
    
    /*UploadTask uploadTask = videosfolder.child(id).putFile(await compressvideo());
    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});
    String downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;*/
    final video = await allvideos.child(id).putFile(await compressvideo());
    String url = await video.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return url;

  }
  Future<String> uploadimagestorage(String id) async{
    //dynamic imagesfolder;
   /* UploadTask uploadTask = imagesfolder.child(id).putData(await getpreviewimage());
    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});
    String downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;*/

    final previewimage = await allimages.child(id).putFile(await getpreviewimage());
    String url = await previewimage.ref.getDownloadURL();
    id=url;
    return url;
  }
```

It seems to me something is wrong widget.videopath in the getpreviewimage() method.
I can't figure out how to solve it and also the Null check operator used on a null value exception.